Indexing error from python during dry run of my snakemake workflow
Snakemake version : 7.32.4,
python version : 3.10.14,
linux ubuntu system
I am experiencing a problem with snakemake.
take into consideration that 'ShS-DIF4-rep1' should match 'FC1' unit in my units dataframe
Thank you in advance for the help.
The complete error:
InputFunctionException in rule cutAdapt_pe in file /home/x/snakemake_longRNAseq/workflow/rules/trim.smk, line 1:
Error:
  KeyError: ('ShS-DIF4-rep1', 'FC2')
Wildcards:
  sample=ShS-DIF4-rep1
  unit=FC2
Traceback:
  File "/home/x/snakemake_longRNAseq/workflow/rules/common.smk", line 27, in cutAdapt_rawFastq
  File "/home/x/snakemake_longRNAseq/workflow/rules/common.smk", line 23, in single_end
  File "/home/x/mambaforge/envs/longRNAseq/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1184, in __getitem__
  File "/home/x/mambaforge/envs/longRNAseq/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1368, in _getitem_tuple
  File "/home/x/mambaforge/envs/longRNAseq/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1041, in _getitem_lowerdim
  File "/home/x/mambaforge/envs/longRNAseq/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1153, in _getitem_nested_tuple
  File "/home/x/mambaforge/envs/longRNAseq/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1431, in _getitem_axis
  File "/home/x/mambaforge/envs/longRNAseq/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1381, in _get_label
  File "/home/x/mambaforge/envs/longRNAseq/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 4293, in xs
  File "/home/x/mambaforge/envs/longRNAseq/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/multi.py", line 3222, in _get_loc_level (rule cutAdapt_pe, line 1, /home/x/snakemake_longRNAseq/workflow/rules/trim.smk)

I am expecting for respective 'ShS-DIF4-rep1' to match 'FC1' and same from other samples to match their respective unit column for the same row from my units.tsv table.
Edited version

#Below is the code I used in common.smk file:

    samples = (
    pd.read_csv(config["samples"], dtype = str, sep= "\t")
    .set_index ("sample", drop=False)
)

units = (
    pd.read_csv(config["units"], dtype = str, sep= "\t")
    .set_index(["sample", "unit"], drop=False)
)

units.index = units.index.set_levels(
    [i.astype(str) for i in units.index.levels]
)  # enforce str in index


def single_end(sample, unit):
    return pd.isnull(units.loc[(sample, unit), "fq2"])


def cutAdapt_rawFastq (wildcards):
    if single_end(wildcards.sample, wildcards.unit):
        return units.loc[(wildcards.sample, wildcards.unit), "fq1"]
    else: #paired_end
        return units.loc[(wildcards.sample, wildcards.unit), ["fq1", "fq2"]].dropna()```


#And this is the code I used for both rules in trim.smk file

 ```rule cutAdapt_pe:
       input:
        cutAdapt_rawFastq
       output:
         forwardPaired="results/cutAdapt/{sample}-{unit}.1.fastq.gz",
         reversePaired="results/cutAdapt/{sample}-{unit}.2.fastq.gz",
       threads:
         4
       shell:
         """
         cutadapt -q 20 -m 30 --pair-filter=any --quality-base=33 -j {threads} -a AGATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCA -A AGATCGGAAGAGCGTCGTGTAGGGAAAGAGTGT -o {output.forwardPaired} -p {output.reversePaired} {input[0]} {input[1]}
         """



rule cutAdapt_se:
       input:
        cutAdapt_rawFastq
       output:
         single_end="results/cutAdapt/{sample}-{unit}.fastq.gz"
       threads:
         4
       shell:
         """
         cutadapt -q 20 -m 30 --quality-base=33 -j {threads} -a AGATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCA -o {output.forwardPaired} {input}
         """

#rule all in snakefile:

rule all:
    input:
        expand("results/cutAdapt/{sample}-{unit}.{read}.fastq.gz", sample=samples.index, unit=units["unit"], read = read),
        expand("results/cutAdapt/{sample}-{unit}.fastq.gz", sample=samples.index, unit=units["unit"])  





There's not enough info here to answer your question. The error is occurring in a function defined in the trim.smk file so we would need to at least see that file to be able to tell what the bug is. Is this a workflow you wrote yourself, or one you have downloaded?

Thank you @TimBooth for your comment. I just edited the post and in the edited version part I added my script from common.smk file where I wrote the functions I used as an input for the rules in trim.smk file. If you can check them out please. Thank you.

Thanks for the clarification. So, you have asked Snakemake to create this output file (per the expand(...) expression in rule all):
results/cutAdapt/ShS-DIF4-rep1-FC2.1.fastq.gz
Snakemake sees that the cutAdapt_pe rule can make this output. In this case the wildcards are ambiguous, but regex matching is greedy by default, so Snakemake breaks it down to:
sample=ShS-DIF4-rep1
unit=FC2

Now Snakemake calls cutAdapt_rawFastq(wildcards) which in turn calls single_end("ShS-DIF4-rep1", "FC2"), and this accesses:
units.loc[("ShS-DIF4-rep1", "FC2"), "fq2"]
So you need to make sure this line is present in your units dataframe. By the looks of it, this is missing. You could use a try/except block in the single_end() function to  return a default value.
Looking at the code in general, I'm not sure how the cutAdapt_pe rule is ever going to work on a single_end sequence file. If your input function returns only a single filename then attempting to access {input[1]} will throw an IndexError. I think maybe what you really want to do is to ensure that the expand() function in rule all never asks for a paired output on a single_end sample - ie. do the single_end() check within the rule all inputs rather then the cutAdapt_se and cutAdapt_pe rules.
